# C++ return value reference of std::map

Tags: c++, reference, return, stdmap

I have got a :  `std::map<string,Star> galaxy`  and i want the `find_star()` method below to return a reference to a value in this map. I dont get any compiling Errors but it wont return any reference.

```
Star& Galaxy::find_star(const string& name){
    try{
    return galaxy.at(name);
    }
    catch(out_of_range a){
        cerr<<"Error: "<<a.what()<<" Key not found!"<<endl;
    }
}
```

The debugger receives an unknown signal when passing the "return" line.

```
main.cpp
int main(){
    Galaxy g("stars-newline-leer.txt");
    g.print();
    Star s;
    s=g.find_star("Caph");//Working correctly until here 
return 0;
}

Star.cpp

Star::Star() {
}

Star::Star(const Star& obj) {
    this->id=obj.id;
    this->ms=obj.ms;
    this->prim_id=obj.prim_id;
    this->bez=obj.bez;
    this->sb=obj.sb;
    this->x=obj.x;
    this->y=obj.y;
    this->z=obj.z;


}

Star::~Star() {
}

istream& operator>>(istream& is, Star& obj) {
    string str = "";
    int i = 0;

    getline(is, str); //Id einlesen
    obj.id = stoi(str);

    getline(is, str); //Bezeichnung einlesen
    obj.bez = str;

    getline(is, str); //x-Koordinate
    obj.x = stod(str);

    getline(is, str); //y-Koordinate
    obj.y = stod(str);

    getline(is, str); //z-Koordinate
    obj.z = stod(str);

    getline(is, str); //Sternenbild
    obj.sb = str;

    getline(is, str); //Mehrfachsternsys
    obj.ms = stoi(str);

    getline(is, str); //Primärstern-Id
    obj.prim_id = stoi(str);


    return is;

}



ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, Star& obj) {
    os << "ID: " << obj.id << endl;
    os << "Name: " << obj.bez << endl;
    os << "Koordinaten: " << obj.x;
    os << ", " << obj.y;
    os << ", " << obj.z << endl;
    os << "Sternenbild: " << obj.sb << endl;
    os << "System-Id: " << obj.ms << endl;
    os << "Pimärstern: " << obj.prim_id << endl;
    return os;
}

void Star::print()const {


    cout << "ID: " << id << endl;
    cout << "Name: " << bez << endl;
    cout << "Koordinaten: " <<fixed<< x;
    cout << ", " <<fixed<< y;
    cout << ", " <<fixed<< z << endl;
    cout << "Sternenbild: " << sb << endl;
    cout << "System-Id: " << ms << endl;
    cout << "Pimärstern: " << prim_id << endl;
}
```

Sorry im new to Stackoverflow im not used to this. And why do i need to add non-code to submit my Edit. I think i just said everything about it.

Comment: Looks like it should work.  Can you provide a [mcve] the doesn't?

Comment: So if an exception is caught, what do you expect your function to return?

Comment: Unrelated, but you ought to catch exception objects by reference. Otherwise you lose information due to possible object slicing. `out_of_range ` has no sub-classes. But it's better to be consistent.

Comment: Ah thanks forgot that

Comment: I now edited my Question. It just all works fine : My `print()` method, the constructor until i call the `find_star()` method @NathanOliver

Comment: please be more careful with creating a [mcve]. It will help you and it will help others to help you if you prepare a code that can be reproduced by others. Once again your galaxy is rather irrelvant to the problem, but there are many things that could be wrong in `Star`

Comment: @NathanOliver My Problem was that my strings from my textfile had a `'\r'` character at their end. So my method couldnt find them because i was not entering the correct string. Thanks for your help though .

Answer (score 1):

Your `find_star` function has a design problem, as @CoryKramer commented.

You don't return the `Star` reference when you get `out_of_range` exception, at this point you can throw another exception, but it will turn your code unnecessary complicated...

My recommendation is that you simply use the `map::find` in your main function.

```
int main(){

    Galaxy g("stars-newline-leer.txt");
    g.print();
    Star s;
    map<string,Star>::iterator it = s.find("Caph");
    if(it != m.end())
    {
      //element found;
      s = it->second;
    }
    else
    {
      cout<<"Error: "<< it->first << " Key not found!" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT**

In case you want to use your custom find function that throw (o re-throw the exception) you can do it as follows:

```
Star& Galaxy::find_star(const string& name){
    try{
      return galaxy.at(name);
    }
    catch(const std::out_of_range& a){
      cerr<<"Error: "<<a.what()<<" Key not found!"<<endl;
      throw; //an internal catch block forwards the exception to its external level
    }
}
```

And Then you need to catch the exception again in your `main` block.

```
int main(){
  Galaxy g("stars-newline-leer.txt");
  g.print();
  Star s;
  try{
    s=g.find_star("Caph");
  }
  catch(const std::exception& e){
    //Do something here
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I know about the exception-issue. But my task is to implement a class-method which accepts a string and returns the reference of the object if it exists in the container and throws an exception if not found.

Comment: @PaulFi, Edited to meet your comment!

Comment: Ah okay that seems to be a good solution. Is it possible to have two catch blocks accepting different types of exceptions? Because i already added another catch block already for another exception type. @Rama

Comment: @PaulFi Yes, see Explanation in  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/try_catch